# FormControl Validators

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation

I know this code works for me:

```
this.BridgeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    gateway: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.ipRegex)]],
});
```

but, I would like to be more explicit with the properties:

```
this.BridgeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    gateway: {
        value: "", disabled: false,
        Validators: [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(this.ipRegex),
        ]
    },
});
```

I always get an error with the later in my console like so:

> ERROR Error: The MaskedTextBox component supports only string values.

The issue is with the validators property.  I cannot figure out how to use it like this from the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing FormControl for the property values. The top object (form) will create an instance of FormGroup and every property needs a FormControl where you can define the necessary validators, disabled, etc

Here's the syntax updated to work with your example:

```
this.bridgeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  gateway: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: false }, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(this.ipRegex)
  ])
});
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swbfa3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I see.  I have to explicitly call `new FormControl ()` even though it is a `FormBuilder`.  Thank you.

Comment: You will need to do that for every property you want "control" over